# Cannot Remove Attribute Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If I try the code below on the console in Chrome, it is working. But the code is not working in my Javascript extension in Chrome.

```
var region = document.getElementById("physicalDeliveryOfficeName");
region.removeAttribute("onchange");
```

Any thoughts what am I doing wrong? Tried to add this line in my function and on the top of my script but it is not working.

Comment: Is that script injected into the page, or is it executing in the extension's private environment, and also running after the element exists in the dom

Comment: probably the extension script running before the DOM load ?

Comment: It should work if correct ID and after load. removeAttribute("onchange") works in chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4zqzdupa/

Comment: @PatrickEvans the script that I'm trying to remove is in the page itself

Comment: You probably should consider tagging the question with [tag:google-chrome-extension] before it's too late.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the execution environment that it is [isolated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) in a Chrome extension.

You have to inject the code into the page to do modify the page context handlers.

Please see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 0):

It works in console because the dom has loaded. Wrap your code in an event handler.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var region = document.getElementById("physicalDeliveryOfficeName"); 
  region.removeAttribute("onchange");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: I tried to add the code above in my script but it didn't work as well.